# GreaterOrEqual validator in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Realized few minutes ago that there is no `GreaterOrEqualThan` validator, or a parameter in `GreaterThan` validator that changes its behaviour from `>` to `>=`.

Why? Is it possible to compose `>=` validator using basic zend framework set of validators?

Yes, guys, I know that I can write my own validator, but I'm curious about solution based on native ZF validators ;-)

Comment: What do you want to compare with GreaterOrEqualThan or GreaterThan? I think zend framework implementation ends at some point because it's still a framework that needs to be customized for your needs. However interesting question ;)

Comment: I created my own GT and LT validators that accept a 'strict' option.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD: well, some zend validators accepts additional parameters that control the validator behaviour. Such as "strict" parameter for `identical`, "allowWhiteSpace" for `alnum`, "inclusive" (!!!!!!!) for `between`, etc. So it is "inclusive" for between, but no such option for `greaterThan`. It is not fair ;-)

Comment: @David Weinraub: Yeah, it is easy. My question is just kind of curiosity, may be some one here know what idea they followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd set `array('min' => ($value-1))` and use `GreaterThan`. Maybe use a chain and add `Digits`, so you make sure you're dealing with numbers. Something like this:

```
$value = 10;

$chain = new Zend_Validate();
$chain->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Digits());
$chain->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_GreaterThan(array('min' => ($value-1))));

var_dump($chain->isValid($value), $chain->getMessages());
```

I think that's as far as you get with ZF. Wouldn't hurt to get a feature request though. Would be a nice addition. Otherwise, extend `GreaterThan` and add an option.

Comment: Yes, I used `int` validator and specified `-1.1` value as `min`, since I need `>= -1`. But this looks like a dirty hack ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'd extend GreaterThan and make it work. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: Cool, just checking. :-) Regardless, it would be nice if you added an issue on Zend's Jira and possibly a patch! :-)