# How to validate in Zend Framework if a float/double is equal or greater/less than a min?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate

I've a simple question for which I've not found an answer and that is

How can I use the built-in Zend Validator to test if a **float/dobule** is Greater than or Equal of a min?

I've already searched for an answer that fits my request and I discovered this question [GreaterOrEqual validator in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730075/greaterorequal-validator-in-zend-framework) but mine is a little bit different. Besides, I know that I can create my own Validator or copy one of those that are on the web like this one [Greater Than or Equal Validator](http://www.nickpack.com/article/zend-framework-greaterthan-equalto-validator) but I would like to know how I can do this validation with the built-in validators.

This is an example to let you better understand.

If I had an integer, I can achieve this goal in this way:

```
$Validators = array(new Zend_Validate_Int(), new Zend_Validate_GreaterThan($min - 1));
// Validate the number
```

Instead, If I had a float, I can't do this trick and, as a lot of programmers know, trying to do dirty things with float can create a lot of issue because of the rounding problem ([What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)).

Thanks to all

Comment: The answer is "no", you cannot do this with the built-in validators. It should be fairly trivial to create your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I've tried many ways, I concluded that actually (Zend Framework version 1.11) it's no possibile to do this kind of validation using built-in validators (as suggested by Phil).

I really hope they will add this validator in the next releases.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is possible check the below answer from @rukya.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what You asked for, but I think it's the simplest:
The key is 'inlusive'.

```
    $number->addValidator('Float');
    $number->addValidator('Between', false,array('min' => '5,5', 'max' => $greatest_number+1, 'inclusive' => true));
```

here You have all the validators:

[Zend_Validate_Abstract Class Reference](http://zendframeworkdocumentation.com/classZend__Validate__Abstract.html)

so the answer for Your question is 'no', there isn't Greater Than or Equal Validator for floats.

Answer (score -1):

What about using

> new Zend_Validate_Callback(
>         function ($value) {
>           if ($value >= 1) {
>             return true;
>           }
>           return false; });